# iOS app Sqlite Prepare statement error when inserting long html string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing issue when inserting long html string in sqlite database in my iOS app.

I am getting a long html content which is dynamically pulled from mail server. Example html content is below.

[I NEED TO STORE THE ENTIRE HTML STRING. BECAUSE I'll HAVE TO GET THIS STRING BACK AGAIN AND LOAD IN UIWEBVIEW]

```
    <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;"><div style="background-color:#eee">                                  
    <div><b>From:</b> martin test &lt;martintest@gmail.com&gt;</div>                                                   
    <div><b>To:</b> Steve test &lt;stevetest@yahoo.com&gt;, martin test &lt;martintest@gmail.com&gt;</div>                                                                                                      
<div><b>Subject:</b> This for testing</div>                                                   
<div><b>Date:</b> July 8, 2015 at 11:05:05 AM GMT+5:30</div>                 
</div></div><div><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div dir="ltr">This is a testing email.<br />
            <div><br /></div>
            <div>How are you?</div>
            <div><br /></div>
            <div>Best of Luck.</div>
            <div><br /></div>
            <div>Bye take care.</div>
            <div><br /></div>
            <div><br /></div>
            <div>Regards,</div>
            <div>Martin</div>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
            </div>
```

When I am trying to insert sqlite database like below,

```
    - (void) storeMailContent:(NSString*)emailAddress foldername:(NSString*)folderName msguid:(unsigned int)msgUID msgcontent:(NSString *)msgContent { 
// msgContent is HTML LONG STRING

        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into OfflineMailsDBTable (emailid, foldername, uid, content) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", %d, \"%@\")", emailAddress, folderName, (int)msgUID, msgContent];
                    NSLog(@"insertSQL: %@", insertSQL);

                    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [emailAddress UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [folderName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, (int)msgUID);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [msgContent UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


                        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"inserted the values in table");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSLog(@" not inserted the values in table");
                            NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    }
                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    sqlite3_close(database);
                    NSLog(@"db closed");
                }

    }
```

It is giving error as,

```
Problem with prepare statement: near "padding": syntax error
```

when executing the below line,

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into OfflineMailsDBTable (emailid, foldername, uid, content) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", %d, \"%@\")", emailAddress, folderName, (int)msgUID, msgContent];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the double quotes in your HTML content before adding it to the INSERT statement.

Assuming that the HTML content is stored in the variable *msgContent* you should do something like:

```
NSString *escapedMsgContent = [msgContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into OfflineMailsDBTable (emailid, foldername, uid, content) values (\"%@\", \"%@\", %d, \"%@\")", emailAddress, folderName, (int)msgUID, escapedMsgContent];
```